# How to make fadeIn() and hide() work only for tablet and desktop versions?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have the following CSS to keep one of my page elements hidden initially:

```
@media only screen {
  #page-element-1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and the following JS to fadeIn the element when another element is clicked.:

```
$('page-element-2').click(function(){
  $('#page-element-1').fadeIn();
}
```

However I want to fade in the element only on tablets and desktops.
How can I do this?

I did try wrapping the js in something like: `if (screen.width >= 769){}`. But even with this, when I resize the browser, I do see the `#page-element-1` as

```
element.style {
  display:block
}
```

overrides:

```
#page-element-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Rather than initiating the fade like that, use CSS transitions to apply the desired effect, using media queries to target the desired devices and then just use JS to toggle the class.

Comment: I hope you know that users won't naturally resize the browser, right ? Most of the time, they are either on phone or computer (+ tablet). Thus, using a ìf(screen.width >= 769) {}`might be enough if it's working. Or, you'll have to create handlers who will check on resize. The best solution I can see is the one above, by @Shaggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, rather than trying to apply the effect through JavaScript, instead use CSS transitions to do so, targeting the resolutions you want with media queries and then just use JS to initiate the effect by toggling a class.

Here's a pure JS proof of concept, click on the green div to reveal the red div above:

```js
document.getElementById("shown").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementById("hidden").classList.toggle("shown");
},0);
```

```css
#hidden{
    background:red;
    height:0;
}
@media all and (min-width:769px){
    #hidden{
        opacity:0;
    }
    #hidden.shown{
        opacity:1;
        transition:opacity .5s;
    }
}
#hidden.shown{
    height:100px;
}
#shown{
    background:green;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hidden"></div>
<div id="shown"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of key factors here.

1. Make sure you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in your `<head>` element.
2. As @Shaggy said, you need to use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for the desired effect.

example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {  // tablets can't go below 768px
    #someID {
       // styles
    }
}
```

Additional media queries [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for selected devices

3. As for your javascript calculating the resize of your browser, this only works on doc load UNLESS you're using `resize` event.

   ```
   $(window).on('resize', function() {
       // throw your resize code here for whatever you want to hide/show
       if (window.screen.availWidth > 768 {
              ......
       }
   });
   ```

You don't necessarily have to use *both* the `resize` event AND the media queries. Once you resize the browser, the media queries will pick up the width and assign styles to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

best way, as others suggested, is using keyframes in css.

if you wanted to do it in javascript, try:

```
if ($(window).width() < 796) {
    //DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To see the change you should use the mobile emulation available in chrome and firefox, and reload the page. That and use the [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Media_queries).